# LegrandOrangeBook class change font family for chapters in preamble

Tags: fonts, document-classes, fontfamily, custom, legrandorangebook

I’m really struggling to change the font family for the part, chapter, and section headings in the [Legrand Orange Book class](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book). I what that to be changed in the preamble of my `main.tex` with some google font that I downloaded.

So far here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
fleqn, 
a4paper,
]{LegrandOrangeBook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\chapterimage{orange1.jpg} % Chapter heading image
\chapterspaceabove{6.5cm} % Default whitespace from the top of the page to the chapter title on chapter pages
\chapterspacebelow{6.75cm} % Default amount of vertical whitespace from the top margin to the start of the text on chapter pages

\setmainfont[ % Selected specific google font
Path = ./static/Rubik/static/,
Extension = .ttf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
BoldFont = *-Medium,
ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-MediumItalic,
]{Rubik}
\newfontfamily{\chapterfont}{Quicksand}[ % Selected specific google font
Path = ./static/Quicksand/static/,
Extension = .ttf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

Although it does compile, it does not set the proper font.

I tried to redefine `\titleformat` as such in the preamble of `main.tex`:

```
\titleformat
{\chapter} % Section type being modified
[block] % Shape type, can be: hang, block, display, runin, leftmargin, rightmargin, drop, wrap, frame
{\chapterfont}{\outputchaptertitle{\thechapter}{#1}} % Format of the whole section
{} % Format of the section label
{0cm} % Space between the title and label
{} % Code before the label
[] % Code after the label
```

Although it does compile, it does not set the proper font, and it spits the following errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} 
[…]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.101 ^^I\chapter{Title}
[…]
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.101 ^^I\chapter{Title}
```

I’m not sure I understand the problems messages here.