# Babel package doesn't work with template

Tags: babel, templates, legrandorangebook

I'm using the [Legrand Orange Book template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book) (you can download the tex file from there or open it in Overleaf) and I am currently trying to obtain a document with the spanish language specs, but using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` provides several errors about sectioning, all of them are missing or extra `\endcsname`.

I thought it could be because I put the `babel` command after loading the book class, which is included in the Legrand Orange Book LaTeX class.

MWE code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{LegrandOrangeBook}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{0, 100, 100}

\chapterspaceabove{6.5cm}
\chapterspacebelow{6.75cm}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [text opacity=1, minimum height=0.2\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth, text width=0.8\paperwidth] at (10,-5) {\sffamily 
        {\Huge\bfseries The$\,\,$ document$\,\,$ title\par}
        \vspace{16pt} % Vertical whitespace
        {\LARGE Blablabla\par} % Subtitle
        \vspace{24pt} % Vertical whitespace
        {\huge\bfseries Your$\,\,$ Name\par}
        \vspace{10pt}
        {\LARGE Tutor: }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages
\tableofcontents % Output the table of contents
\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable default headers and footers again
\cleardoublepage % Start the following content on a new page


\chapterspaceabove{6.75cm} 
\chapterspacebelow{7.25cm} 

\chapter{Sectioning Examples}\index{Sectioning}

\section{Section Title}\index{Sectioning!Sections}
Lorem ipsum

\subsection{Subsection Title}\index{Sectioning!Subsections}
Fusce varius orci

\end{document}
```

In order to run this, you need to enter the link I posted before, go to "download template code" and include the LegrandOrangeBook file and the tex file with my MWE in the same folder.

Comment: Please provide an example, that compiles AND shows your problem. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO The MWE I provided shows my problem. You just need to comment the line '\usepackage[spanish]{babel}' to compile it properly

Comment: Ok. This class seems to provide at least one other nasty feature: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700257/legrandorangebook-class-change-font-family-for-chapters-in-preamble . May be it‘s a good idea to contact the author of tis class?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if all what you do make sense, but this one at least compiles:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{LegrandOrangeBook}

 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage{csquotes}      % <<< was missing

 \definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{0, 100, 100}

\chapterspaceabove{6.5cm}
\chapterspacebelow{6.75cm}

% \usepackage{svg} % <<< not needed here

\begin{document}


 \thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [text opacity=1, minimum height=0.2\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth, text width=0.8\paperwidth] at (10,-5) {\sffamily 
        {\Huge\bfseries The$\,\,$ document$\,\,$ title\par}
        \vspace{16pt} % Vertical whitespace
        {\LARGE Blablabla\par} % Subtitle
        \vspace{24pt} % Vertical whitespace
        {\huge\bfseries Your$\,\,$ Name\par}
        \vspace{10pt}
        {\LARGE Tutor: }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    

 \pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages
 % !!! trouble ahead
% \tableofcontents % Output the table of contents
 \pagestyle{fancy} % Enable default headers and footers again
 \cleardoublepage % Start the following content on a new page


\chapterspaceabove{6.75cm} 
\chapterspacebelow{7.25cm} 

\chapter{Sectioning Examples}\index{Sectioning}

\section{Section Title}\index{Sectioning!Sections}
Lorem ipsum

\subsection{Subsection Title}\index{Sectioning!Subsections}
Fusce varius orci

\end{document}
```

Procedure:

- commented out everything, besides some kind of "hello world" left
- uncommented step by step
- found that one package was missing
- > trouble maker `\tableofcontents`

One warning or error remains, which is related to the documentclass:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperindex' has already been used, 
setting the option has no effect on input line 507.
```

Comment: I still need the table of contents to be printed...

Comment: With reference to my first sentence I suggest to restart from scratch. Just enter basic text, i.e do not enter all the bells and whistles yet like formattings, index, etc. Perhaps you didn’t typeset the titlepage correctly. Start with class article, which works nicely with TOC. Once that compiles, switch to the orange-class. Work in small steps, just like climbing high altitude mountains: from safe to safe. So when you fail to compile, you know your last action which caused trouble.In general do content first, and layout last.